# A function that only permits N concurrent threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# .NET 3.5 project where a class listens for an event invocation from another class that is multithreaded. I need to ensure that my event only allows simultaneous access to a maximum of 10 threads. The 11th thread should block until one of the 10 finishes.

```
myobj.SomeEvent += OnSomeEvent;

private void OnSomeEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs args)
{
    // allow up to 10 threads simultaneous access. Block the 11th thread.
    using (SomeThreadLock lock = new SomeThreadLock(10))
    {         
        DoUsefulThings(args.foo);
    }
}
```

I do not have control over the other `MyObj` class, so I cannot implement a threadpool there.

What is the best way to implement this?

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want the [Semaphore class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx).  It is, in short, a lock that only allows a specified number of callers through at any time.

Since you don't control the creation of threads, you do need to be careful about deadlock situations.  Semaphores are not reentrancy-aware- if a given thread enters a semaphore more than once, it will take more than one slot.  So if each of your caller's threads enters your semaphore more than once, there is the possibility of a deadlock.

Answer (score 9):

Use a `Semaphore` for this. The constructor parameters are a little confusing to those just getting introduced to the class. The first parameter specifies the initial number of threads allowed through *right now*. The second parameter specifies the maximum number of threads allowed through at any given time.

```
myobj.SomeEvent += OnSomeEvent;
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(10, 10);

private void OnSomeEvent(object sender, MyEventArgs args)
{
  semaphore.WaitOne();
  try
  {
    DoUsefulThings(args.foo);
  }
  finally
  {
    semaphore.Release();
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for noting that you should exit the semaphore in the `finally` block of a try/catch.  This is important stuff- in case your code throws an exception, you want to make sure the semaphore is exited.

Answer (score 3):

It's customary to use a semaphore for this.  Initialize it to 10 units.  wait() for one unit before DoUsefulThings(), signal() one unit afterwards.